# runCommand で ec2-user としてコマンドを実行するには?

Tags: aws

aws の runCommand は、ユーザーが root の状態でコマンドを実行します。

ec2-user として実行したい条件があったので、以下の command でもって runShellScript を実行しました。

```
su ec2-user && whoami
```

結果は以下で、 su が正しくできていない様子です。

```
root
```

#### 質問

- amazon linux に対して runCommand をする際に、 ec2-user として実行したいです。これはどうやったら実現できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

su の使い方が違ってますね。
`su ec2-user -c "whoami"` でうまくいく気がします。

Comment: su は、自分の shell session をスタートしているんですね。。そういえば手元でもそんな感じでした。

Answer (score 2):

[AWS Lambda Python 3.6 - SSM to EC2 - executes commands as root rather than user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50647809/3090068) が、おそらく似たような質問だと思っています。 (未解決ですが)

それによると、 [runuser コマンド](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/runuser/) だとうまくいくそうです。

試しに以下を実行したところ、`ec2-user` が表示されて、ひとまず自分のやりたいことは達成できました。

```
/sbin/runuser -l ec2-user -c 'whoami'
```